# How to properly do nested imports for scss?Semantic-UI issues?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

Currently I am trying to use Semantic UI with my react application. It is currently altering the whole applications css. I looked up a solution to do nested scss imports to isolate it to a div. While doing so I get this error:

./src/components/_EmployeeRES.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/components/_EmployeeRES.scss)
Module not found: Can't resolve './semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css' in 'C:\Users\silve\desktop\Java_Project\my-app\src\components'

Here are the files that I am working with:

_semantic-ui.scss:

```
.semantic-ui{
    @import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
}
```

_EmployeeRes.scss

```
.profile-icons{
    @import 'semantic-ui';
}
```

EmployeeRES.js

```
import React from 'react'

import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'
import './_EmployeeRES.scss'
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import ClickAwayListener from '@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener'
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem'
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu'
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import { Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Link } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

...


export const Profile = ({visible, closeProfile,customStyle}) => (
  <Modal
    isOpen={visible}
    onRequestClose={()=>closeProfile()}
    style={customStyle}>
        <div className='profile-container'>
            <div style={{textAlign:'center' ,fontSize: '16px', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Profile</div>
            <div className='profile-pic-container'></div>
            <div style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:'14px', marginTop: '10px'}}>
                <div>{'First Name Last Name'}</div>
                <div>{'Position'}</div>
                <div>{'City, State'}</div>
            </div>
             <div className='profile-icons'>
                <Icon name='phone' color='green' size='large'/>
            </div> 
        </div>
  </Modal>
)
```

All these files are in the same directory.

Comment: Is the `semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css` also in the same folder? If not, I believe you should be using an absolute path to the `node_module` folder.

Comment: @eMontielG yes all these files are in the same directory. So what would the absolute path look like? are you talking about the import in the _EmployeeRes.scss file? So .profile-icons { @ import///file path} ? and where would i find that file path?

Comment: I think with SASS you can just do  ` @import '~semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'`. But since you said that file is also in the same folder as the one importing it, I don't think it will work. I thought you used npm to install semantic-ui.

Comment: @eMontielG I did install semantic ui by command line. The one in the import in _EnployeeRES.scss comes from the class inside the other scss file. I saw a solution to do a nested import for the semantic ui css file. So this was the solution I was trying to replicate. But I get the node module error. So I was wondering what was wrong with the nested import ? Or is it another issue entirely? My problem I'm trying to solve is when I import the semantic ui css in the file directly it alters the css of the entire application. I'm open to another solution. This is the only solution I found though.

Comment: Where is `semantic.min.css` located?

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with nested imports, but your issue depends on where that file is located. I can give you other possible solutions if the `~` import didn't work. You could try removing the `.css` extention, like `@import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min'`, or maybe adding `./` to the beginning: `@import './semantic-ui-css/semantic.min'`.

Comment: @eMontielG, the import '~semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css' worked. So thank you!

Comment: @eMontielG actually when i do the ~ before semantic its still affecting the entire application with the semantic ui css, and when i remove the css extension it doesnt apply the sematic UI css

Comment: @eMontielG the css file is in node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css , i also see there is a semantic.css file within the same folder

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with the imports anymore, are you only using the `.semantic-ui` class in HTML elements whose children you want to target?

Comment: @eMontielG, if you look at my profile component in the code above you see I have a div with a class called 'profile-icons', and the nested import is for that specific class as you can see in the code above with my css files. But it still targets the whole application when imported through the nested imports. So the error is gone. Just need to fix that it is targeting everywhere not just the specific div I want to apply it to

Comment: @eMontielG, in my import statement in the nested import, I have it directly importing it from the node modules folder : ../../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css

Comment: @eMontielG, so to be clear, im importing the semantic-ui css file into the profile-icons class in the other css file.

Comment: So, your class nesting should look like this: `.profile-icons .semantic-ui .[all semantic-ui classes]`, right? But it is also styling classes outside `.profile-icons`?

Comment: @eMontielG ya so i have the class .profile-icons{
    import './semantic-ui';
} which imports the semantic-ui scss file. The semantic scss file contains  .semantic-ui{
    import '../../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
}

Comment: @eMontielG, ya the styling applies to the entire application. So not even restricted to the component. It applies to every page. Which I need it to only apply to the profile-icons class

Comment: Weird, have you checked to see if the classes are in fact nested in the CSS output? I guess you could try to use mixins `@mixin semantic-ui { @import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'; } ... .profile-icons { .semantic-ui { @include semantic-ui } }`. What does your webpack config look like?

Comment: @eMontielG I tried the mixin solution you put but i got the error  : no mixin named semantic-ui. For the webpack config, I dont believe I have set up that file. I currently do not have one. Unless Im looking in the wrong place. Also I do not have experience with writing that file.

Comment: What does your CSS output look like?

Comment: @eMontielG css output : https://imgur.com/a/BWbreFL

Comment: I mean the CSS file that gets outputted when you build your project.

Comment: @eMontielG I dont think there is a generated css file... Unless im missing something. Here is my src directory: https://imgur.com/a/Hv1cGnp

Comment: Found the issue. This comment thread is already too big, I'm going to reply with an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue you're having is because you're not importing the Semantic UI library correctly. It should be:

```
.semantic-ui{
    @import '~semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
}
```

The `~` tells webpack to look for that file within the `node_modules` folder. Without it, the SASS parcer will look inside your current directory, and if it can't find it there, it will search through the directories defined via the [--load-path](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#load-path) argument (CLI), or the [includePaths](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api#includepaths) (JS API).

The second issue is that you should be ommiting the `.css` extention when importing CSS files inside SASS. If you don't, they will be translated into normal CSS import rules, `@import url(...)`, which is why your semantic-ui rules aren't being nested within the `.profile-icons`class. Try:

```
.semantic-ui{
    @import '~semantic-ui-css/semantic.min';
}
```

For some reason `@font-face` rules defined inside the `semantic.min.css` file will stop working if you nest your rules like this. Not sure if it's invalid CSS or if webpack can't figure out the files' location. A quick fix would be to redefine them at the top level of your project, inside `index.css` perhaps:

```
// index.css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Icons";
  src: url("~semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff")
    format("woff");
}
```

Comment: this fixes the css portion but the Icon does not render. This is my current format: .semantic-ui{
    import '~semantic-ui-css/semantic.min';
} , and in the other file is : .profile-icons{
    import 'semantic-ui';
}

Comment: it works actually, but for some reason the size prop on the Icon is messing it up. When i remove size it renders, but when i have the size prop it doesnt show

Comment: If you inspect the icon, what rules does it have?

Comment: using the chrome dev tools to inspect. It does not show up to inspect. Here is the documentation for the icon, https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon/ , which i do not see any required props

Comment: It should be there, components just get turned into plain HTML in the end. It should be an `<i>` tag with a class similar to: `i.large.icon, i.large.icons`.

Comment: here is what i am getting from the dev tools, https://imgur.com/a/A4zrOq8

Comment: The styles aren't being applied, probably due to the `.semantic-ui` class interfering with the actual nesting of your components. Try importing the library inside your `_EmployeeRes.scss`'s `.profile-icons` directly, like: `.profile-icons{ @import '~semantic-ui-css/semantic.min'; }`.

Comment: doing that is getting some response, the icons are showing up as boxes now but not fully displaying https://imgur.com/a/q7VqGER

Comment: Not sure why but If you nest the semantic-ui css, its `@font-face` definitions stop working, will update answer with fix.

Comment: just letting you know it worked! thank you so much for your time and help.